# lossless conversion of float to string and back: is it possible?

Tags: string, floating-point, floating-accuracy

This question refers to the IEEE standard floating point numbers used on C/x86.

Is it possible to represent any numeric (i.e. excluding special values such as NaN) float or double as a decimal string such that converting that string back to a float/double will always yield exactly the original number?

If not, what algorithm tells me whether a given number will suffer a conversion error?

If so, consider this: some decimal fractions, when converted to binary, will not be numerically the same as the original decimal value, but the reverse is not true (because the binary has bounded precision so any decimal expansion is finite and perfect if not truncated), so here's another question...

Is it ever necessary to introduce deliberate errors into the decimal representation in order to trick the `atof` (or other) function into yielding the exact original number, or will a naive, non-truncating `toString` function be adequate (assuming exact conversion is possible in general)?

Comment: What language/environment? From the symbols you mention, it could be JavaScript, or it could be C, or it could be something else entirely. (A native `toString` will almost certainly *not* be adequate for a genuinely lossless round-trip.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [this page](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?joel.3.653326.31):

> Actually, the IEEE754-1985 standard says that 17 decimal digits is
>   enough in all cases. However, it seems that the standard is a little
>   vague on whether conforming implementations must guarantee lossless
>   conversion when 17 digits are used.

So storing a `double` as a decimal string with at least 17 digits (correctly rounded) will guarantee that it can be converted back to binary `double` without any data loss.

In other words, if every single possible double-precision value were to be converted to a decimal string of 17 digits (correctly rounded), they will all map to different values. Thus there is no data-loss.

---

I'm not sure on the minimum cut-off for single-precision though. But I'd suspect that it will be 8 or 9 digits.

Comment: It is 9 digits for floats (see page 4 of http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/ieee754status/IEEE754.PDF; also, see Goldberg's paper, section "Binary to Decimal Conversion".)

Comment: You mention "correctly rounded". Isn't that a loophole? Which implementations generally won't or can't adhere to? Also, do actual implementations meet this theoretical guarantee?

Answer (score 1):

Given that the IEEE format can only represent a finite number of (binary) digits, and therefore have a minimum accuracy (cf. epsilon), you will only need a finite number of (decimal) digits. Of course it is preferable if the implementation (`strtod`, `snprintf`) has an identity mapping behavior between {all floats} and the set of {one decimal representation for each float}.

Answer (score 0):

In java, it is possible to convert double from/to string, by constructing an intermediate BigDecimal object:

```
double doubleValue = ...;

// From double to string
String valueOfDoubleAsString = new BigDecimal(doubleValue).toString();
// And back
double doubleValueFromString = new BigDecimal(valueOfDoubleAsString).doubleValue();

// doubleValue == doubleValueFromString
```

There is no locale issue with this method.
However, special double values (Infinite, NaN) will of course not work.

Answer (score 0):

In C, there is a flag `a` to the `printf`  that will write an exact representation of IEEE doubles, as in

```
double f;
printf("%a", f);
```

This is documented in the *man page*. The result can be read with `scanf`.

In python , you can use any of

```
s = '%a' % f
s = ascii(f)
s = repr(f)
```

this is guaranteed to print a representation that can be cast back to the original float

```
s = '%a' % f
assert f == float(s)
```