# Best IEEE 754-1985 representation for X3.9-1978 based standard

Tags: c, floating-point, precision, dicom

As per DICOM standard, a type of floating point can be stored using a Value Representation of Decimal String. See [Table 6.2-1. DICOM Value Representations](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part05/sect_6.2.html#table_6.2-1):

> Decimal String: A string of characters representing either a fixed
>   point number or a floating point number. A fixed point number shall
>   contain only the characters 0-9 with an optional leading "+" or "-"
>   and an optional "." to mark the decimal point. A floating point number
>   shall be conveyed as defined in ANSI X3.9, with an "E" or "e" to
>   indicate the start of the exponent. Decimal Strings may be padded with
>   leading or trailing spaces. Embedded spaces are not allowed.
>
> "0"-"9", "+", "-", "E", "e", "." and the SPACE character of Default
>   Character Repertoire. 16 bytes maximum

So I would be tempted to simply use 64 bits `double` (`IEEE 754-1985`) to represent the value in memory in my C code, based on the fact that input is stored on a maximum of 16 bytes.

Could someone with a little bif more knowledge of `X3.9-1978` confirms that this is the best possible representation (compared to `arbitrary-precision`, `float` and/or `long double`) ? By best, I mean the representation were round-trip read/write will be *visually lossless*. I should be able to read such ASCII floating point representation from disk, put it into memory, and write it back to disk (as specified above) with maximum accuracy compared to the original values (= machine epsilon when possible). The actual implementation details on how to represent a `double` as ASCII with only 16 bytes of storage is outside the scope of this question, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32631178/writing-ieee-754-1985-double-as-ascii-on-a-limited-16-bytes-string) for details..

Comment: IEEE 754 binary64 isn't *quite* good enough to be able to round-trip all these values, but it's pretty close.  The only place you're potentially going to lose information is with odd 16-digit integers between `9007199254740993` and `9999999999999999` with no sign.  E.g., the 16-character strings `9999999999999997` and `9999999999999996` would both map to the same IEEE 754 binary64 float value.  The moment you have a sign, or a decimal point, or an exponent, you have 15 or fewer significant digits, which the binary64 format will handle faithfully.  Same for 16-digit integers smaller than 2**53.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is heavily based on Hans Passant's and Mark Dickinson's comments.

Using any floating point type to represent decimal values is generally a bad idea because binary floating point types cannot *exactly* represent decimal values. Typically never use them for processing exact monetary values.

But here, DICOM spec sets the limit to 16 characters, when the precision of a double is about 15-16 decimal digits ([ref.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)). As soon as your decimal string contains one sign (+/-), a dot (.) or an exponent part (e/E), you will have at most 15 decimal digits and a round trip should be correct. The only problems should occur when you have 16 digits. The example provided by Mark Dickinson is: *the 16-character strings `9999999999999997` and `9999999999999996` would both map to the same IEEE 754 binary64 float value.*

TL/DR: Hans Passant gave a nice abstract: *"16 bytes maximum" [is] exactly as many accurate significant digits you can store in a double. This DICOM spec was written to let you use double. So just use it*

---

Disclaimer: All values acceptable in IEEE 754 will be correctly processed, but beware, `1e1024` will be an acceptable value for a DICOM Decimal String, but it in not representable in a double (limited at about 1e308).

Comment: [IEEE754-1985 standard says that 17 decimal digits is enough in all cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8990831/136285)

Comment: @malat: what is said there is that you can convert back and forth *from a double value to a 17 character decimal string*. What **I** say here, is that the *decimal value* `0.1` cannot be converted exactly to a double value. If you do, that double will indeed be back and forth convertible to a 17 character decimal string, but that string will not be `0.1`...

Comment: If I give you a 16 character decimal string, there are cases where it can be represented by two distinct ieee 754 double (we would need 17 character decimal string to disambiguates them). So depending on the implementation one DICOM VR:DS value can be represented by more than one `double` value. This could be added/clarified in your answer IMHO.