# Writing IEEE 754-1985 double as ASCII on a limited 16 bytes string

Tags: c, floating-point, precision

This is a follow-up to my [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32629084/best-ieee-754-1985-representation-for-x3-9-1978-based-standard). But I'll repeat it for clarity:

As per DICOM standard, a type of floating point can be stored using a Value Representation of Decimal String. See [Table 6.2-1. DICOM Value Representations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32629084/best-ieee-754-1985-representation-for-x3-9-1978-based-standard):

> Decimal String: A string of characters representing either a fixed
>   point number or a floating point number. A fixed point number shall
>   contain only the characters 0-9 with an optional leading "+" or "-"
>   and an optional "." to mark the decimal point. A floating point number
>   shall be conveyed as defined in ANSI X3.9, with an "E" or "e" to
>   indicate the start of the exponent. Decimal Strings may be padded with
>   leading or trailing spaces. Embedded spaces are not allowed.
>
> "0"-"9", "+", "-", "E", "e", "." and the SPACE character of Default
>   Character Repertoire. 16 bytes maximum

The standard is saying that *the textual representation* is fixed point vs. floating point.  The standard only refers to how the values are represented within in the DICOM data set itself. As such there is not requirement to load a fixed point textual representation into a fixed-point variable.

So now that this is clear that DICOM standard implicitely recommend `double` (IEEE 754-1985) for representing a `Value Representation` of type `Decimal String` (maximum of 16 significant digits). My question is how do I use the standard C I/O library to convert back this binary representation from memory into ASCII onto this limited sized string ?

From random source on internet, this is non-trivial, but a generally [accepted solution](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/03/08/float-precisionfrom-zero-to-100-digits-2/) is either:

```
printf("%1.16e\n", d); // Round-trippable double, always with an exponent
```

or

```
printf("%.17g\n", d); // Round-trippable double, shortest possible
```

Of course both expression are invalid in my case since they can produce output much longer than my limited maximum of **16 bytes**. So what is the solution to **minimizing the loss in precision** when writing out an arbitrary double value to a limited 16 bytes string ?

---

**Edit**: if this is not clear, I am required to follow the standard. I cannot use hex/uuencode encoding.

**Edit 2**: I am running the comparison using travis-ci see: [here](https://travis-ci.org/malaterre/dicomds)

So far the suggested codes are:

1. [Serge Ballesta](https://github.com/malaterre/dicomds/blob/master/compute1.c)
2. [chux](https://github.com/malaterre/dicomds/blob/master/compute2.c)
3. [Mark Dickinson](https://github.com/malaterre/dicomds/blob/master/compute3.c)
4. [chux](https://github.com/malaterre/dicomds/blob/master/compute4.c)

Results I see over here are:

- `compute1.c` leads to a total sum error of: `0.0095729050923877828`
- `compute2.c` leads to a total sum error of: `0.21764383725715469`
- `compute3.c` leads to a total sum error of: `4.050031792674619`
- `compute4.c` leads to a total sum error of: `0.001287056579548422`

So `compute4.c` leads to the best possible precision (0.001287056579548422 < 4.050031792674619), but triple (x3) the overall execution time (only tested in debug mode using `time` command).

Comment: Can the string contain `\0`? If so you could memcpy a 64 bit double into char[8] with some shenanigans for endianness if necessary.

Comment: You meant `[8]`, right?

Comment: These values represent physical readings, right?  What do you *really* lose if you just represent everything in the form `'%+16.8e'` (for example)?  Is an error of one part in a billion unsustainable for your application?

Comment: @MarkDickinson your comment should be an answer ! thanks much. I'll do my homework and actually compute the tradeoffs (loss, portability...) for each proposed solutions here.

Comment: Is exponential notation _required_?  Is "1234567890123456" OK?

Comment: @chux of course not, this is perfectly valid (per my understanding of the standard).

Comment: Per my read, "A floating point number **shall be conveyed** as defined in ANSI X3.9, **with** an "E" or "e" ..." does not allow  "1234567890123456".  But if it is OK by you and this post, then OK.  Now the task is a bit harder.

Comment: Per my read " A fixed point number shall contain only the characters 0-9 with an optional leading "+" or "-" and an optional "." to mark the decimal point." does not apply to `double` as it is floating point and not fixed point.  But of course,only a small part of the spec is posted here.

Comment: Suggest patience on this question.  there are some deep issues here.  For [quick answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32631178/writing-ieee-754-1985-double-as-ascii-on-a-limited-16-bytes-string?noredirect=1#comment53139315_32631178)

Comment: "triple (x3) the overall execution time" --> triple of what?  of `printf("%.17g\n", d);`?  What is the "total sum error" of the base-line method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is trickier than first thought.

Given the various corner cases, it seems best to try at a high precision and then work down as needed.

1. Any negative number prints the same as a positive number with 1 less precision due to the `'-'`.
2. `'+'` sign not needed at the beginning of the string nor after the `'e'`.
3. `'.'` not needed.
4. Dangerous to use anything other than `sprintf()` to do the mathematical part given so *many* corner cases.  Given various rounding modes, `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`, etc., leave the heavy coding to well established functions.
5. When an attempt is too long by more than 1 character, iterations can be saved.  E.g. If an attempt, with precision 14, resulted with a width of 20, no need to try precision 13 and 12, just go to 11.
6. Scaling of the exponent due to the removal of the `'.'`, must be done after `sprintf()` to 1) avoid injecting computational error 2) decrementing a `double` to below its minimum exponent.
7. Maximum relative error is less than 1 part in 2,000,000,000 as with `-1.00000000049999e-200`. Average relative error about 1 part in 50,000,000,000.
8. 14 digit precision, the highest, occurs with numbers like `12345678901234e1` so start with 16-2 digits.

---

```
static size_t shrink(char *fp_buffer) {
  int lead, expo;
  long long mant;
  int n0, n1;
  int n = sscanf(fp_buffer, "%d.%n%lld%ne%d", &lead, &n0, &mant, &n1, &expo);
  assert(n == 3);
  return sprintf(fp_buffer, "%d%0*llde%d", lead, n1 - n0, mant,
          expo - (n1 - n0));
}

int x16printf(char *dest, size_t width, double value) {
  if (!isfinite(value)) return 1;

  if (width < 5) return 2;
  if (signbit(value)) {
    value = -value;
    strcpy(dest++, "-");
    width--;
  }
  int precision = width - 2;
  while (precision > 0) {
    char buffer[width + 10];
    // %.*e prints 1 digit, '.' and then `precision - 1` digits
    snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, "%.*e", precision - 1, value);
    size_t n = shrink(buffer);
    if (n <= width) {
      strcpy(dest, buffer);
      return 0;
    }
    if (n > width + 1) precision -= n - width - 1;
    else precision--;
  }
  return 3;
}
```

Test code

```
double rand_double(void) {
  union {
    double d;
    unsigned char uc[sizeof(double)];
  } u;
  do {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(double); i++) {
      u.uc[i] = rand();
    }
  } while (!isfinite(u.d));
  return u.d;
}

void x16printf_test(double value) {
  printf("%-27.*e", 17, value);
  char buf[16+1];
  buf[0] = 0;
  int y = x16printf(buf, sizeof buf - 1, value);
  printf(" %d\n", y);
  printf("'%s'\n", buf);
}


int main(void) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    x16printf_test(rand_double());
}
```

Output

```
-1.55736829786841915e+118   0
'-15573682979e108'
-3.06117209691283956e+125   0
'-30611720969e115'
8.05005611774356367e+175    0
'805005611774e164'
-1.06083057094522472e+132   0
'-10608305709e122'
3.39265065244054607e-209    0
'33926506524e-219'
-2.36818580315246204e-244   0
'-2368185803e-253'
7.91188576978592497e+301    0
'791188576979e290'
-1.40513111051994779e-53    0
'-14051311105e-63'
-1.37897140950449389e-14    0
'-13789714095e-24'
-2.15869805640288206e+125   0
'-21586980564e115'
```

Answer (score 2):

C library formatter has no direct format for your requirement. At a simple level, if you can accept the *waste* of characters of the standard `%g` format (`e20` is written `e+020`: 2 chars wasted), you can:

- generate the output for the `%.17g` format
- if it is greater the 16 characters, compute the precision that would lead to 16
- generate the output for that format.

Code could look like:

```
void encode(double f, char *buf) {
    char line[40];
    char format[8];
    int prec;
    int l;

    l = sprintf(line, "%.17g", f);
    if (l > 16) {
        prec = 33 - strlen(line);
        l = sprintf(line, "%.*g", prec, f);
        while(l > 16) {
            /* putc('.', stdout);*/
            prec -=1;
            l = sprintf(line, "%.*g", prec, f);
        }
    }
    strcpy(buf, line);
}
```

---

If you really try to be optimal (meaning write e30 instead of e+030), you could try to use %1.16e format and post-process the output. Rationale (for positive numbers):

- the `%1.16e` format allows you to separate the mantissa and the exponent (base 10)
- if the exponenent is between size-2 (included) and size (excluded): just correctly round the mantissa to the int part and display it
- if the exponent is between 0 and size-2 (both included): display the rounded mantissa with the dot correctly placed
- if the exponent is between -1 and -3 (both included): start with a dot, add eventual `0` and fill with rounded mantissa
- else use a `e` format with minimal size for the exponent part and fill with the rounded mantissa

Corner cases:

- for negative numbers, put a starting `-` and add the display for the opposite number and size-1
- rounding : if first rejected digit is `>=5`, increase preceding number and iterate if it was a `9`. Process `9.9999999999...` as a special case rounded to 10

Possible code:

```
void clean(char *mant) {
    char *ix = mant + strlen(mant) - 1;
    while(('0' == *ix) && (ix > mant)) {
        *ix-- = '\0';
    }
    if ('.' == *ix) {
        *ix = '\0';
    }
}

int add1(char *buf, int n) {
    if (n < 0) return 1;
    if (buf[n] == '9') {
        buf[n] = '0';
        return add1(buf, n-1);
    }
    else {
        buf[n] += 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int doround(char *buf, unsigned int n) {
    char c;
    if (n >= strlen(buf)) return 0;
    c = buf[n];
    buf[n] = 0;
    if ((c >= '5') && (c <= '9')) return add1(buf, n-1);
    return 0;
}

int roundat(char *buf, unsigned int i, int iexp) {
    if (doround(buf, i) != 0) {
        iexp += 1;
        switch(iexp) {
            case -2:
                strcpy(buf, ".01");
                break;
            case -1:
                strcpy(buf, ".1");
                break;
            case 0:
                strcpy(buf, "1.");
                break;
            case 1:
                strcpy(buf, "10");
                break;
            case 2:
                strcpy(buf, "100");
                break;
            default:
                sprintf(buf, "1e%d", iexp);
        }
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void encode(double f, char *buf, int size) {
    char line[40];
    char *mant = line + 1;
    int iexp, lexp, i;
    char exp[6];

    if (f < 0) {
        f = -f;
        size -= 1;
        *buf++ = '-';
    }
    sprintf(line, "%1.16e", f);
    if (line[0] == '-') {
        f = -f;
    size -= 1;
    *buf++ = '-';
    sprintf(line, "%1.16e", f);
    }
    *mant = line[0];
    i = strcspn(mant, "eE");
    mant[i] = '\0';
    iexp = strtol(mant + i + 1, NULL, 10);
    lexp = sprintf(exp, "e%d", iexp);
    if ((iexp >= size) || (iexp < -3)) {
        i = roundat(mant, size - 1 -lexp, iexp);
        if(i == 1) {
            strcpy(buf, mant);
            return;
        }
        buf[0] = mant[0];
        buf[1] = '.';
        strncpy(buf + i + 2, mant + 1, size - 2 - lexp);
        buf[size-lexp] = 0;
        clean(buf);
        strcat(buf, exp);
    }
    else if (iexp >= size - 2) {
        roundat(mant, iexp + 1, iexp);
        strcpy(buf, mant);
    }
    else if (iexp >= 0) {
        i = roundat(mant, size - 1, iexp);
        if (i == 1) {
            strcpy(buf, mant);
            return;
        }
        strncpy(buf, mant, iexp + 1);
        buf[iexp + 1] = '.';
        strncpy(buf + iexp + 2, mant + iexp + 1, size - iexp - 1);
        buf[size] = 0;
        clean(buf);
    }
    else {
        int j;
        i = roundat(mant, size + 1 + iexp, iexp);
        if (i == 1) {
            strcpy(buf, mant);
            return;
        }
        buf[0] = '.';
        for(j=0; j< -1 - iexp; j++) {
            buf[j+1] = '0';
        }
        if ((i == 1) && (iexp != -1)) {
            buf[-iexp] = '1';
            buf++;
        }
        strncpy(buf - iexp, mant, size + 1 + iexp);
        buf[size] = 0;
        clean(buf);
    }
}
```

Comment: Simplification suggestion: `sprintf(format,"%%.%2dg", prec); sprintf(line, format, f);` --> `sprintf(line, "%.*g", prec, f);` and use return value for length.

Comment: @malat: If you really try to be optimal (meaning write `e30` instead of `e+030`), you could try to use `%1.16e` format and post-process the output. But there are many corner cases. I will elaborate on it and propose some code, probably in a couple of days.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I believe there is a bug in your code, see results (`sum`) from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/malaterre/dicomds/master/compute1.c)

Comment: Examining the textual exponent generated by `sprintf(line, "%1.16e", f)` is  a good idea to find extra for the mantissa.  Attempting to manipulate `line` though may incur double rounding errors: the round done by `sprintf()` and the round done by `round(char *buf, unsigned int i, int iexp)`.  Also: Recommend new name to not contradict with `<math.h. `round(double)`.

Comment: @chux: name changed to `roundat`. But I cannot imagine how to avoid the double rounding, except by calling a new time sprintf. Format `"%1.16e` gives maximum precision, but to store the string in only 16 characters forces to round it at 10 to 14 digits as soon as I use e notation. That's why I call it *optimal* precision and not *maximum* precision.

Comment: @malat: I cannot accurately represent all floating point values in only 16 characters, As soon as you need a `e-10`, mantissa has only 12 possible digits, where the double precision allows for 16, so the 4 least significant digits are lost.

Comment: @SergeBallesta that does not explain the huge value for sum. I see a `3.402823466385e+38` over here, hence my suspicion for a bug.

Comment: Agree about "except by calling a new time sprintf."  The trick is `double`s just smaller than a power-of-ten like e-100, e-10, e-1, e0, e1, e10, e100 that when rounded one digit more or less also change the exponent width.

Comment: @malat: each individual error should have a magnitude between 1e-11 and 1e-16, UINT32_MAX is about 4e10. I would expect sum to be between  1e-2 and 1.  3e38 effectively suggests a bug, but do you know for which value the individual relative error is greater than  1e-10?

Comment: @malat: I could find 2 bugs in my code, One is because -0. needs special processing (-0. < 0 is false...), the other is when exponent is 15 and mantissa has more than 16 decimal digits. Still some more tests and I'll post a fix.

Comment: @malat: I've fixed my code. Now I used it in your test and result is  `sum: 0.096028574904409816
nmissed: 16777215
Elapsed: 12283.554688 seconds` - But I also changed size used to call encode to 16 and not 17, and ensured that `delta()` always returns positive values.

Answer (score 2):

For finite floating point values the `printf()` format specifier `"%e"` well matches
"A floating point number shall be ... with an "E" or "e" to indicate the start of the exponent"

```
[−]d.ddd...ddde±dd
```

The sign is present with negative numbers and likely `-0.0`.  The exponent is at least 2 digits.

If we *assume* `DBL_MAX < 1e1000`, (safe for [IEEE 754-1985 double](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985)), then the below works in all cases: 1 optional sign, 1 lead digit, `'.'`, 8 digits, `'e'`, sign, up to 3 digits.

(Note: the "16 bytes maximum" does not seem to refer to C string null character termination.  Adjust by 1 if needed.)

```
// Room for 16 printable characters.
char buf[16+1];
int n = snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%.*e", 8, x);
assert(n >= 0 && n < sizeof buf);
puts(buf);
```

But this reserves room for the *optional* sign and 2 to 3 exponent digits.

The trick is the boundary, due to rounding, of when a number uses 2 or uses 3 exponent digits is fuzzy.  Even testing for negative numbers, the `-0.0` is an issue.

[Edit] Also needed test for very small numbers.

Candidate:

```
// Room for 16 printable characters.
char buf[16+1];
assert(isfinite(x)); // for now, only address finite numbers

int precision = 8+1+1;
if (signbit(x)) precision--;  // Or simply `if (x <= 0.0) precision--;`
if (fabs(x) >= 9.99999999e99) precision--; // some refinement possible here.
else if (fabs(x) <= 1.0e-99) precision--;
int n = snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%.*e", precision, x);
assert(n >= 0 && n < sizeof buf);
puts(buf);
```

---

Additional concerns:

Some compilers print at least 3 exponent digits.
The maximum number of decimal significant digits for `IEEE 754-1985 double` *needed* varies on definition of need, but likely about 15-17.  [Printf width specifier to maintain precision of floating-point value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16839658/2410359)

Candidate 2:  One time test for too long an output

```
// Room for N printable characters.
#define N 16
char buf[N+1];
assert(isfinite(x)); // for now, only address finite numbers

int precision = N - 2 - 4;  // 1.xxxxxxxxxxe-dd
if (signbit(x)) precision--;
int n = snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%.*e", precision, x);
if (n >= sizeof buf) {
  n = snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%.*e", precision - (n - sizeof buf) - 1, x);
}
assert(n >= 0 && n < sizeof buf);
puts(buf);
```

Comment: @OP Other code could be use to fine tune the `if (fabs(x) >= 9.99999999e99) precision--;` test.  Using `x < -9.999999994e99 || x > 9.9999999994e99` is one.  IMO a general used repeated test call to `snprintf()` is a CPU sink-hole x2 or trying to be too clever is will fail some corner case.  Code as needed to deal with values near this boundary.

Comment: The value of `n` can be greater than `sizeof buf`, since `n` simply indicate if the string has been truncated or not. Eg: `x = pow(0.5, 1022 + 52)`

Comment: @malat Answer amended to cope with tiny numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best option is to use printf("%.17g\n", d); to generate an initial answer and then trim it. The simplest way to trim it is to drop digits from the end of the mantissa until it fits. This actually works very well but will not minimize the error because you are truncating instead of rounding to nearest.

A better solution would be to examine the digits to be removed, treating them as an n-digit number between 0.0 and 1.0, so '49' would be 0.49. If their value is less than 0.5 then just remove them. If their value is greater than 0.50 then increment the printed value in its decimal form. That is, add one to the last digit, with wrap-around and carry as needed. Any trailing zeroes that are created should be trimmed.

The only time this becomes a problem is if the carry propagates all the way to the first digit and overflows it from 9 to zero. This might be impossible, but I don't know for sure. In this case (+9.99999e17) the answer would be +1e18, so as long as you have tests for that case you should be fine.

So, print the number, split it into sign/mantissa strings and an exponent integer, and string manipulate them to get your result.

Comment: 1) "If their value is greater than 0.50 then increment the printed value in its decimal form." and that in turn can lead to 9.999 becoming 1.000 with an incremented exponent that was 99 and now 100 needing another  truncated digit '0' in the mantissa.  2)  code is also double rounding: the `0.5000` may have been a un-rounded `0.49999999` and now this text rounding is doing it again.  The general idea is sound, but the corner cases are a challenge and frankly prone to significant error.

Comment: I don't think the corner cases are that bad - rounding a decimal number correctly is fairly straightforward. A few tests to check the corner cases should suffice. The double rounding is a problem but has a limited effect on the result (maximum error of 0.55 ULPs instead of 0.5 ULPs?).

Comment: Agree with the small effect of correct double rounding consider it is the ULP of display digits and not ULP of the `double`.  Recall that correct rounding also entail the current rounding mode.  My experience of reviewing carry math on text has too often came up with a missing case like considering numbers about `1e100` , `1e10` `1e-10`, which propagate a carry to the exponent digits too.

Answer (score 0):

Printing in decimal cannot work because for some numbers a 17 digit mantissa is needed which uses up all of your space without printing the exponent. To be more precise, printing a double in decimal sometimes requires more than 16 characters to guarantee accurate round-tripping.

Instead you should print the underlying binary representation using hexadecimal. This will use exactly 16 bytes, assuming that a null-terminator isn't needed.

If you want to print the results using fewer than 16 bytes then you can basically uuencode it. That is, use more than 16 digits so that you can squeeze more bits into each digit. If you use 64 different characters (six bits) then a 64-bit double can be printed in eleven characters. Not very readable, but tradeoffs must be made.

Comment: As per my original question, I am looking for `minimizing the loss`. I know this was a difficult issue (hence my original post referenced in my question).

Comment: Interesting idea if code is not limited to "Decimal String".

Comment: I'll try again with a loss-minimizing answer.