# What is a portable format to fully express a double-precision value in Fortran?

Tags: formatting, fortran, ascii, precision, portability

Suppose I wish to write a double-precision value to an ASCII file to its full precision in a portable manner. (Obviously raw binary output is the most compact way to express a number, but that's not what I'm asking here.)

**I want another program, written in e.g. MATLAB or Python, to be able to read the file and store the same exact value as the Fortran program has internally.**

The default ASCII output is simply done as follows:

```
program main
   use, intrinsic :: ISO_FORTRAN_ENV, only : dp=>REAL64, stdout=>OUTPUT_UNIT
   implicit none

   real(kind=dp), parameter :: pi = 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197_dp

   write(stdout,*) pi            ! Test the default format 
   write(stdout,'(f)') pi        ! Test the specific decimal default format
   write(stdout,'(f20.15)') pi   ! Probably sufficient precision...
   write(stdout,'(f30.20)') pi   ! EXCESSIVE PRECISION!

end program main
```

I understand that different compilers may have different formatting defaults and requirements. For instance, `ifort` compiles the above example without issue and produces the following output:

```
   3.14159265358979
       3.1415926535897931
   3.141592653589793
        3.14159265358979311600
```

`gfortran` (gcc version 4.8.2), on the other hand, requires a width for the second output statement, so compilation fails. Commenting out that second output statement `'(f)'` allows compilation, and the result (with a blank line added here) is:

```
   3.1415926535897931

   3.141592653589793
        3.14159265358979311600
```

I do not have access to `nagfor` and have not installed any other Fortran compilers, so I do not test them here.

You'll notice that the results vary. I expect that none of the results are exact, but rather exact to machine precision. Of course ~15 digits is acceptable for most purposes, but I'm curious about full-precision output so a number can be passed between programs via ASCII output without loss of precision.

## My Question

Is there a portable way to output a `real` to full precision? I'm specifically asking for double-precision `real`s, but if there's a `kind`-independent way to do that, I'd give preference to that answer. Presumably one could use the "EXCESSIVE PRECISION" approach, but bonus points for conciseness, too.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use binary (fortran stream io)?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no reliable way to represent a floating point binary number in decimal without rounding error or vice versa. The last number that you print out (which is the same on both compilers) is the closest decimal representation of the closest binary representation of pi as you entered it in your source code.

Comment: As my more verbose comment didn't take, I'll point out that 17 significant digits is sufficient for exact conversion within the range where f format is satisfactory.   The code for more generality hasn't required change in 25 years.

Comment: Just as a quick comment the format `'(f)'` is not allowed by the standard. It should always be of the form `'(Fw.d)'`.

Comment: Mostly when people think about numbers, they have [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) in mind. However, the Fortran standard does not state that a `REAL` of any kind should conform IEEE-754. It could as well be the IBM HFP format or the MIL-STD-1750A standard. Are you searching a portable way to convert from any format to any format in a generic form?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's generally the case that if you have three more decimal digits than the datatype can represent, you won't lose any bits. So for double precision IEEE float, that would be 18 digits.

Your second format uses a non-standard syntax that ifort supports but gfortran does not. I don't recommend its use.

Fortran 2018 offers "hex format" for real values, that preserves all the bits, but I think only C/C++ understands it.

Comment: Just wondering, you are referring here to `EXw.d[Ee]` data-edit-descriptor?

Comment: Yes. An example value is:

−15.625 EX14.4E3 -0X1.F400P+003

Answer (score 3):

The format you want is ES24.17

Comment: Why this format specifically? Why ES, or 24, or 17?

Comment: why 17? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8990454/lossless-conversion-of-float-to-string-and-back-is-it-possible. why 24? to accommodate all the rest and to keep Intel compiler happy. why ES? so as not waste the first digit as E format does.

Comment: Are you saying I should use `es24.17` as the format specifier, as in `write(*,'(es24.17)') pi`? Or is this a standard? Assuming you mean that it's the format specifier, I echo @Ross's question: why that one?